# How to center absolute positioned items

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to absolutely position a text on top of my image, but it doesnt seem to be centerd. i tried something, but it was very odd. i am going for a responsive site, but with that, it starts to look odd. here is my code.

HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <h1> Richy Photography </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(image.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
body, html
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.parent {
    position:relative;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    left:37%;
    top:37%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the 37% top and left offsets, the text will appear off screen if the viewport is too small.

An easier solution would be to simply set your `.parent` element to display as a `table`, then set your `.child` element to display as a `table-cell` with horizontally and vertically aligned content:

```css
.parent {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.child {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6NvZg/).

This is supported on [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) from IE8 onwards.

In order to then get the content to display on top of the background image, you'll need to give your `.parent` element a higher `z-index` property and give it relative positioning:

```css
.parent {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6NvZg/1/).

Although you could simply give your `.parent` element the background and drop the `#container` element completely.

Comment: the text isn't appearing when i do that

Comment: @user3219918 I must have been editing my answer when you tried it. Please see my updated answer as it should solve that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change width as wat ever you want and now You can remove left also :

```
.child {
position: absolute;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
}
```

because absolute positioned element does not cover the whole width of the relative elements 
so you need to specify by yourself and you can noe use  text-align:center

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KQtYN/)

Comment: Due to the 37% top and left offsets, the text will appear off screen if the viewport is too small.

Comment: It isnt really centered when i do it. from the bottom there is a little more space than the top. but horizontally it is fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KQtYN/1/  


its working fyn bro have a look
http://jsfiddle.net/KQtYN/1/

Comment: you can add top:37%; according to ur need its upto you . otherwise its working fyn :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not rely on left: 37%; in order to center your element across different screen sizes.
Try `left: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%;` this should keep your `.child` element centred no matter what size the parent has.

If you really need position: absolute; try this out, otherwise go with @James Donnelly answer, it's batter.

Have fun and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Setting left and right margins to auto, adding a width, and using left:0; and right: 0; should work.

Something like this:

```
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width:26%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```